# problems with files caching

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My application displays a large images with TileView - images are loaded from the server by tiles. Downloaded tiles are cached during the work.

To cache tiles, I use SDImageCache - it is designed so that all files are stored in one directory. 
All is well, except for one thing: when the number of files exceeds several thousand, the speed of access to the files is reduced and clearing the cache spans a very long time (minutes).

To clear the cache I use [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: error:].

My first thought was to modify SDImageCache so that the files are stored out in separate directories - this should improve the access time to files, but the time of clearing the cache will not be affected.

1) Is there any possibility to quickly remove a directory?

2) Can someone tell a different approach to caching? For example, a cache such as the swap file in Windows?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Use **Three20** library Which caches the images

to remove the image from cache in case the loading is from cache

[[TTURLCache sharedCache] removeURL:CACHED_IMAGE_URL fromDisk:YES];